# How can we find the last item entered within a column

Tags: excel

How can we find the last item entered within a column?(note that the last entered item may be A4, while we have data till A1000)

Thanks

Comment: please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask .

Answer (score 0):

I would create a helper column. This would be a date stamp that is generated using VBA. You can hide we'll just call it column B.

this will go under worksheet change event

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Column = 1 Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Me.Cells(Target.Row, 2) = Format(Date + Time, "mm/dd/yyyy h:nn:ss")
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If End Sub
```

Please note that in `Me.Cells(Target.Row,2)` the 2 is going to change according to which column you want your date in.

this will go in a separate Module:

```
Sub get_LastEntered()
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Dim last_Time As Date
    Dim last_Row As Long
    Dim last_Row_Changed As Long

    last_Row = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
    last_Time = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(ws.Range("B1:B" & last_Row))

    last_Row_Changed = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(last_Time, ws.Range("B1:B" & last_Row),0)

    MsgBox "The last Cell that you changed was:" & last_Row_Changed

End Sub
```

Comment: Its considered a canonical practise to suspend event handling with `application.enableevents = false` before writing to the same worksheet in order that you do not initiate another event and have the [Worksheet_Change](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839775.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) event macro attempt to run on top of itself. Of course, turning events back on with `application.enableevents = true` before exiting is likewise a fairly standard practise.

Answer (score 0):

If you need the **value** of the last item entered, then include this event macro in the worksheet code area:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim CellsToWatch As Range, LastValue As Range
    Set CellsToWatch = Range("A1:A1000")
    Set LastValue = Range("B1")

    If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    If Intersect(Target, CellsToWatch) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    Application.EnableEvents = False
        LastValue.Value = Target.Value
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

If you need the **location** of the last item entered, then use this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim CellsToWatch As Range, LastValue As Range
    Set CellsToWatch = Range("A1:A1000")
    Set LastValue = Range("B1")

    If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    If Intersect(Target, CellsToWatch) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    Application.EnableEvents = False
        LastValue.Value = Target.Address
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

The result will be stored in cell **B1**